# Jquery Cookbook Modal button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, modal-dialog, button

I've been at this for two days and can't seem to get it. Basically, I'm using the JQuery Cookbook modal from scratch. My problem is the form html page loads fine but the code will not recognize my submit button. Here's the relevant parts of the code:

Separate HTML:

```
<div id="contact">
  <form action="" id="register_form" method="post">
    <p>First Name <br />
      <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /></p>
    <p>Last Name <br />
      <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /></p>
    <p>Username: <span class="micro">Must be a valid email address</span></span><br />
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Register" id="register" /></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant parts of the modal code:

```
// Insert modal at end of </body>.
$('body').append('<div id="modal_wrapper"><!--[if IE 6]><iframe id="modal_iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe><![endif]--><div id="modal_overlay"></div><div id="modal_window"><div id="modal_bar"><strong>Modal window</strong><a href="#" id="modal_close">Close</a></div><div id="modal_content"><div id="contact"><form><p><input id="firstname" /></p><p><input id="register" /></p></form></div></div></div>');

$('#modal_content').load('mediaKitF.html#contact'.replace('#', ' #'), '', showModal);

$("input[type=text]").focus(function(){
  // Select field contents
  this.select();
});

$('input #firstname').focus();

$('#register').click(function () {
  alert("hello there");
});
```

Comment: what do you mean, 'will not recognize' - what happens? does it not render on the page? does it not submit?

Comment: Nothing responds when I click the #register button on the modal. The register button is actually HTML from the external page and not the parent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#modal_content').load()` is an asynchronous method, which means that you are trying to attach your click event to the `$('#register')` element before receiving the new content. You need to either use `$('#register').live('click', function() {})` or move the code attaching the click handler into your `showModal` function.

Comment: Well if that's not the golden arrow - worked like a charm! A thousand and one thanks on this Friday!!!